# Unclosed Macroscopic equation from the statistical moments in kinetic theory of gases

Tags: theoretical-physics, boltzmann

I'm interested in kinetic theory of gases, notably its history.

I know that, after the pioneering work of Boltzmann who derived the Boltzmann equation, it is possible by taking its statistical moment to obtain a set of equations that are closely linked to the Navier-Stokes equation.

This system can be closed either by doing a Hilbert expansion, Chapman-Enskog expansion, Grad's 13 moments and so on ...

However, I've not encountered WHO obtained this unclosed system. Who did plug and write the set of equations obtained from taking zeroth, first and second moment of the distribution function to obtain a Navier-Stokes like system ?

Anybody got a source or informations about it ?

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but from papers and book I've seen over the years in library browsing maybe look at publications by [Clifford Truesdell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_Truesdell). Also papers published in volumes of journals Truesdell was an editor of,  *Archive for Rational Mechanics* and *Analysis and Archive for History of Exact Sciences* -- for each journal quickly glance over the table of contents of each volume, beginning with volume 1.

Comment: You may want to check the Wikipedia article on the [BBGKY hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBGKY_hierarchy) which contains links to the original articles by Bogoliubov, Born, Green, Kirkwood and Yvon.

Comment: @TomHeinzl Thanks. Sadly, the BBGKY hierarchy comes after the work of Hilbert (1912), Chapman and Enskog (1916-1917). I presume the link to the macroscopic equations were already clarified by them or before them, or am I wrong ? by 1940 I was thinking it was already fully grasped

Comment: I'm not an expert, but [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266312072_Hilbert_on_kinetic_theory_and_radiation_theory_1912-1914) contains a brief discussion of Hilbert's contribution (based on a lecture delivered 1911-12 and attended by Enskog) together with many useful references (requires access to ResearchGate).

Comment: @TomHeinzl Thanks, i've read this (very interesting) article, but it led to German publications I can't understand. I've also read what I could of Hilbert's publication and didn't even see what other writers imply he wrote, so I think my non-fluentness in German is too much of a hurdle. I'm quite flabbergasted that nobody mentioned such a discovery explicitely... For me it was Hilbert, I dont recall Boltzmann finding a relation to macroscopic governing equations, but I don't find any sources that can confirm ...

Comment: I had a look at Hilbert's paper in the _Mathematische Annalen_ from 1912. Note that this article coincides with the last chapter from his book on linear integral equations. He applies this theory to a perturbative analysis of Boltzmann's equation and finds 5 conditions - his eq. (27). These correspond to the zeroth, first and second moments of Boltzmann's equation, that is mass conservation, Navier-Stokes and energy conservation. A translation of Hilbert's article is in S.G. Brush's third volume on kinetic theory.

Comment: Interestingly, Hilbert states that his hydrodynamic equations have "already been recognised by Maxwell" - but does not give a reference. The only reference to previous work is H. A. Lorentz, Gesammelte Abhandlungen, Bd. I, S. 88. According to Hilbert, Lorentz has found an equation equivalent to Hilbert's eq. (11), governing the first-order correction.

Comment: Thanks for your research ! I will check on Brush's translation. So a hint may be that Maxwell, post 1872, found them